# attribute override concept in multiple inheritance (Django-Mixin)

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, mixins, django-class-based-views

Please refer to following code:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from .models import Course

class OwnerMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(OwnerMixin, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)    

class OwnerCourseMixin(OwnerMixin):
    model = Course

class CourseDeleteView(OwnerCourseMixin, DeleteView):
    template_name = 'courses/manage/course/delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_course_list')
```

I could easily understand that by adding `template_name` and `success_url` attribute in `CourseDeleteView`, I could override the attribute in `DeleteView`. So that the two attributes take effect by calling the method in `DeleteView`.

What confused me is why could I transfer the attribute `model = Course` in `OwnerCourseMixin` to `DeleteView` by the code above. There's no direct inheritance-relationship between them. It makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't transfer the `model` attribute to `DeleteView`, but to `CourseDeleteView` only, since this is the class that inherits from `OwnerCourseMixin`.

If you instantiated `DeleteView`, that instance wouldn't have `model = Course` since, as you cleverly stated, there's no direct inheritance between them. However, an instance of `CourseDeleteView` would have `model = Course`,  which it inherited from `OwnerCourseMixin`.